# Feature Walkthrough, detecting when the .introTour has finished

Tags: jquery, yui

I've written a website tour with the jQuery plugin [Feature Walkthrough](https://github.com/nbprithv/introtour-ui)

```
<button id="yui-galleryintrotourui-buttontourend-id" class="yui-galleryintrotourui-card-next yui3-button notice" data-seqid="end"> … </button>
```

This is pretty much how I'm currently attempting to check if the jQuery function `introTour` has finished, `tour_cards` example is available on the [website](http://nbprithv.github.io/introtour-ui/).

```
$().introTour(tour_cards, function(){
    alert("Finished");
});
```

I've tried using a `.live('click', function(){});` event to pick up, the click event once it has been made on the `yui-galleryintrotourui-buttontourend-id`, but it doesn't do anything (I think, it is because, these events must be added before the elements are added to the DOM itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive just added two events you can subscribe to
https://github.com/nbprithv/introtour-ui#events

I hope this helps.

This is available on the jQuery plugin. 
Ill be updating the YUI plugin with this soon.

Thanks for checking out my work.

Answer (score 1):

Because closeIntro() effectively does this ...

```
$(".yui-galleryintrotourui-card").css("display","none");
```

You could actively poll for the visibility of .yui-galleryintrotourui-card like so ...

```
var isTourOver = setInterval(function(){


    if($('.yui-galleryintrotourui-card:visible').length == 0){

        // The Tour is over!
        clearInterval(isTourOver);
    }

}, 100);
```